# track status changes in JIRA

Tags: jira, jql

I'm interested in status transitions for a project, I've below query which works, however it just shows one line for each item.

I need to have columns with date of status changed, status changed from and status changed to.

`project = "<myProject>" and status CHANGED AFTER '2024-02-07'`

Comment: I don't know jql, but it seems your query just has the conditions on what to match, not any fields to output. If this is like sql, you'd have to specify the fields you want to see. A [mcve] would also help.

Comment: this is a working query in JQL, I insert it (of course inserting a real project name) and it'll run. Unlike SQL, here output fields are defined separately. (and that's where I'm stuck)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't possible using the Jira UI.

JQL returns a list of Jira issues that match the query, but doesn't do anything about presentation of that data - that's the job of the UI itself and can't be customised on a query by query basis.

Note that data returned for an issue is **current** data, even if you queried about a status in the past.  For example, `status WAS IN ("In Progress") DURING (2024-01-01, 2024-01-07)` could return some issues showing the status as "Done", as that's their current status.

If you're happy to do some programming, you can use the [Jira REST API](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-examples/) to pull the data and process it into the output that you want.  Using the `expand=changelog` option in your API call will return the ticket history, including field value changes with a timestamp and what they changed from and to.  You could then loop through the statuses and dump them to a CSV file:

```
Key     Timestamp    From          To
--      --           --            --
JRA-1   2024-01-01   To Do         In Progress
JRA-1   2024-01-03   In Progress   Done
JRA-2   2024-01-06   To Do         In Progress
JRA-2   2024-01-08   In Progress   Done
```